# Patched Delphi library for unicode support in TPageProducer callbacks?

Tags: delphi, winapi, http, indy

I've been using Delphi 2009 with the Indy library (10) that ships and have been upgrading a legacy application that makes heavy use of the TPageProducer.  The legacy app was originally written for Delphi 5 / Indy 8.

I'm using the OnHTMLTag property of TPageProducer to specify a function that will handle the HTML transparent tags in my source.  My problem was that if I put unicode (Simplified Chinese) characters in the TPageProducer.HTMLDoc property, when the OnHTMLTag callback was called, the TagParams argument contains ?? instead of the expected Chinese characters.

I traced this down to around line 2053 of HTTPApp.pas where we separate out the key / value pairs of the transparent tag:

```
procedure ExtractHeaderFields(Separators, WhiteSpace: TSysCharSet; Content: PChar;
  Strings: TStrings; Decode: Boolean; StripQuotes: Boolean = False);

...
if Decode then
  Strings.Add(string(HTTPDecode(AnsiString(DoStripQuotes(ExtractedField)))))
else
  Strings.Add(DoStripQuotes(ExtractedField));
...
```

Everything is fine until we cast the string to an AnsiString and pass it to HTTPDecode, at which point my Strings list contains ?? as does my final TagParams and webpage.

Should there be a version of HTTPDecode that works with Strings instead of AnsiStrings? If so, where might I find this?

For now, I've just disabled the decode routine when I parse my tokens for the TPageProducer, but it isn't a nice fix and would prefer to have a version of this that works with wide characters (if that is even possible).

Comment: As a note to my future self, I created a unicode version of the HTTPDecode function using PChar instead of PAnsiChars, etc. and it appears to be working fine.